# Mac App Store + Silverlight out of browser, would it ever work?

Tags: silverlight-oob, mac-app-store

Yeah I know it's a dumb question, and that of course it wouldn't work. Any kind of work around I can think it stands very little chance of being accepted...

For example what about an accessory application for say printing that launches the main Silverlight application website where the user clicks install. Would that work?...

Anyone else out there working on a Silverlight app and would love to be able to market through the app store?

Comment: silverlightmarket.com seems to have died.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you wanted but check this out: http://silverlightmarket.com

Comment: Interesting. Do you know who is behind it?

Comment: Yes, send me PM on twitter.com/ashleyrudland and I'll give you all the details...

Answer (score -3):

Many OOB features of Silverlight relies on COM availability and they will not work on Mac. C# - Monotouch might be usefule here - http://monotouch.net/Documentation

Comment: This is not true.  The VAST majority of Silverlight features work identically cross-platform.  COM interop is one of very few examples of features that work on Windows only - and of course in the case of COM it's because COM isn't on Mac.

Comment: I know about Mono for Mac, in fact if we were to create an accessory app to launch the Silverlight app, it would be made with Mono.  The question is can that be done... Something I might explore closer to our gold plating stage...